# i want to combine two awk scripts

Tags: linux, awk

I have two with AWK which works perfectly

## myScript3.awk

```
    #!/usr/bin/awk -f
    BEGIN {
        FS=">|</"
        OFS=","
    }
    {
     data[count++] = $2
     ptint $2
     }
    END{
       print data[2],data[6],data[3], FILENAME
    }
```

The above script will scan the xml document and return the 2nd, 6th, 3rd element along with file name.

```
    for filename in *.xml
    do 
        awk -f myscript3.awk $filename >> out.txt
    done
```

The above script will scan the entire folder and list down xml files and then execute myscript.
i have to merge these two scripts as one.
Thanks for your help

Comment: I see only one awk script, not two.  What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#!/bin/bash
AWKPROG='BEGIN {FS=">|</" OFS=","}
{ data[count++] = $2; ptint $2 }
END {print data[2], data[6], data[3], FILENAME}'
for filename in *.xml;do awk $AWKPROG $filename; done >> out.txt
```

Warning: Untested.

Answer (score 1):

Note about calling conventions: if you're running the script as `awk -f script` you do not need the shabang (`#!`) line at the beginning. Alternatively you can run it with the shabang as `./script` if `script` is executable.

**Answer**

`awk` has `BEGINFILE` and `ENDFILE`, replace `BEGIN`/`END` with them and give the `xml` files as an argument, the following should work:

#### Edit

As noted by Dennis in the comments below, there's no need for `BEGINFILE`. Also note that this requires a fairly recent version of GNU `awk` to work.

**myScript3.awk**

```awk
BEGIN {
  FS=">|</"
  OFS=","
}
{
  data[count++] = $2
  print $2
}
ENDFILE {
   print data[2],data[6],data[3], FILENAME
}
```

Run it like this:

```awk
awk -f myscript.awk *.xml
```

Comment: `BEGINFILE` and `ENDFILE` are new in GNU AWK (`gawk`) 4 and not present in earlier versions of `gawk` or at all in other AWKs. Why would you need to reset `FS` and `OFS` for each file? Just use `BEGIN` for that.

Comment: Yes should have noted that this is a recent feature, but very convenient in this situation. No need to reset `FS` and `OFS`, I'll fix that.